# how can i use svchost.exe to host my own services?

Tags: c#, registry

I have written a service in C#.  I kept the DLLs of my service in c:\windows\system32\myservice.dll.  I have done the necessary registry changes for hosting in svchost.exe, but my service is not being executed.  It gets a 1053 error code.

The following is the registry entry for myservice. I created a key and have given the path of the myservice.dll file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\svcsvc2]
"Type"=dword:00000010
"Start"=dword:00000002
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
"ImagePath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
00,76,00,63,00,68,00,6f,00,73,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2d,00,\
6b,00,20,00,4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,53,00,65,00,72,00,76,00,69,00,63,\
00,65,00,00,00
"DisplayName"="@%SystemRoot%\\system32\\svcsvc.dll,-200"
"ObjectName"="NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService"
"ServiceSidType"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\svcsvc2\Parameter]
"ServiceDll"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,\
00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,\
73,00,76,00,63,00,73,00,76,00,63,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ServiceMain"="Main"
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839174

Comment: Followup on your questions or accept answers sreeee.

Answer (score 3):

1053 is `ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT`

> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a
>   timely fashion.

StartServiceCtrlDispatcher was not called?

You also have type set to `SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS`, not `SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS`.

And please respect [this note from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Note that Svchost.exe is reserved for use by the operating system and
>   should not be used by non-Windows services. Instead, developers should
>   implement their own service hosting programs.

Answer (score 1):

svchost doesn't host the .NET framework, so is not able to execute your .NET assembly.

.NET services run with their own applications (.exe).

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating a Setup Project in VS that installs your service?

Unless you want to install a service programatically, I would advise you to read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169) article.